# How to avoid repeated if else series code smell

Tags: c#, code-cleanup

Work on C# 4.5. My bellow syntax so many if else series it seems code smell,want a way to avoid this smell.Any kind of help will be acceptable. Thank you

```
public bool CheckValidCustomer()
{
    return _checkManager.IsCustomerPersonal(_customer) ? IsValidPersonalCustomer() : IsValidCompanyCustomer();
}

private bool IsValidCompanyCustomer()
{
    if (_checkManager.IsValidFinancialInfo(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Financial Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidCompanyInfo(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Company Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidStakeHolderInfo(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Stake Holder Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidResponsiblePersonInfo(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Responsible person Info.";
        return false;
    }


    if (_checkManager.IsValidScreeningInfo(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Screening Info .";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidMyNumberUpload(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check My Number Upload Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidIdUpload(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Id Upload Status.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidCustomerStatus(_customer) == false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Customer Status.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool IsValidPersonalCustomer()
{
    if (_checkManager.IsValidPersonalInfo(_customer)==false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Personal Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidFinancialInfo(_customer)==false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Financial Info.";
        return false;
    }

    if (_checkManager.IsValidCompanyInfo(_customer)==false)
    {
        ProcessMessage = "Please Check Company Info.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Implement a "ValidateCompanyCustomer" of some sort in the Check manager. Implement each "IsValidCompanyInfo" as a validator "Strategy". Each validator strategy could implement a "Check" method. The Check manager would then have an IEnumerable of validator strategies it runs through. You would then also be able to test each validator strategy separately

Comment: Those aren't if/else statements. They're just if statements.

Comment: since this is a **working** piece of code, StackOverflow isn't the right place to post this question.  This belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You may want to check out the [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use validation rule pattern.
[Avoiding many if blocks for validation checking](http://softwaregarden.io/avoiding-many-blocks-validation-checking/)

Create a set of validation rules. And run through all of them one by one. If any one validation rule fails, complete validation fails (depending on business rules).

You can also refer to [WPF Data Binding Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)(Data Validation -> Validation Process section) to get ideas for designing your own validation rules engine.

Answer (score 2):

My personal suggestions:

1. Create a base class Customer, and Two subclasses PersonalCustomer/CompanyCustomer. Validation should be done within these classes - they know their implementation details.
2. Customer base class has a member which is a chain of validation actions, each action item in the chain returns an Enum as a validation result (success o4 specific error)
3. Customer base class has a method Validate, which calls each validation action in the chain and returns if validation fails
4. Each subclass implements the detailed validation action, and registers it into the validation chain. No more checkmanager. caller can just call _customer.Validate() and don't have to worry what type of customer that is.
5. A representation layer to map the enum (error code basically) to some UI specific strings, this can be done via an array/hashset - no more if/else or switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
private bool IsValidCompanyCustomer()
{
    var companyValidationRules = new Dictionary<string, Func<Customer, bool>>
    {
        { "Please Check Financial Info.", _checkManager.IsValidFinancialInfo},
        { "Please Check Company Info.", _checkManager.IsValidCompanyInfo},
        { "Please Check Stake Holder Info.", _checkManager.IsValidStakeHolderInfo},
        { "Please Check Responsible person Info.", _checkManager.IsValidResponsiblePersonInfo},
        { "Please Check Screening Info.", _checkManager.IsValidScreeningInfo},
        { "Please Check My Number Upload Info.", _checkManager.IsValidMyNumberUpload},
        { "Please Check Id Upload Status.", _checkManager.IsValidIdUpload},
        { "Please Check Customer Status.", _checkManager.IsValidCustomerStatus},
    };

    var failedRule = companyValidationRules.Where(d => !d.Value(_customer))
                                           .Select(d => d.Key)
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(failedRule))
    {
        this.ProcessMessage = failedRule;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private bool IsValidPersonalCustomer()
{
    var companyValidationRules = new Dictionary<string, Func<Customer, bool>>
    {
        { "Please Check Personal Info.", _checkManager.IsValidPersonalInfo},
        { "Please Check Financial Info.", _checkManager.IsValidFinancialInfo},
        { "Please Check Company Info.", _checkManager.IsValidCompanyInfo},
    };

    var failedRule = companyValidationRules.Where(d => !d.Value(_customer))
                                           .Select(d => d.Key)
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(failedRule))
    {
        this.ProcessMessage = failedRule;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}